# Issue allocating resources (Number of Mappers) in EMR MapReduce2 YARN

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, emr, hadoop2

I have a very small new EMR cluster to play around with and I'm trying to limit the number of concurrent mappers per node to 2. I tried this by tweaking the default cpu-vcores down to 2.

Formula used:

```
min((yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb / mapreduce.map.memory.mb),
    (yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores / mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores))
```

Cluster configuration:

```
AMI version: 3.3.1
Hadoop distribution: Amazon 2.4.0
Core: 4 m1.large
```

Job Configuration:

```
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb:5120
mapreduce.map.memory.mb:768

yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores: 2
mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores: 1
```

As a result, I am currently seeing 22 mappers running at the same time. Besides being wrong according to the formula, this does not make sense at all giving the I have 4 cores. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't experienced the second part of the formula (the one with *vcores*) to ever take place on small dedicated cluster I worked on (although it should have according to formula). I read somewhere also that *YARN* does not take cpu cores into account when allocating resources (i.e. it only allocates based on memory requirements).

As for the memory calculation, `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` is a per node setting, but dashboards often give you cluster wide numbers, so before you divide the `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` by `mapreduce.map.memory.mb`, multiply it with the number of nodes in your cluster, i.e.

```
(yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb*number_of_nodes_in_cluster) / mapreduce.map.memory.mb
```